# Compile different files where functions and common blocks have the same name

Tags: fortran, namespaces, shared-libraries, intel-fortran

I am currently trying to implement some 3rd party code (program A) within another 3rd party program (program B). Unfortunately, it seems like some `COMMON` blocks and subroutines share names between the two codes. This is not detected by the compiler (I suspect because the compilation process involves many different files and creating a shared object), but the program crashes when accessing certain common blocks / subroutines with very general names (e.g. `BASIS`, `JACOBIAN`), and renaming them alleviates the problem. However, renaming all common blocks and subroutines within program A is not feasible because of its size.

At the moment, I have two seperate directories of code. I compile both seperately with the intel compiler into `.o` files and then create a shared object from both:

```
ifort -c -fPIC -fp-model precise codeA.f
ifort -c -fPIC -fp-model precise codeB.f
ifort -c -fPIC -fp-model precise code_coupling.F90
ld -shared -o library.so codeA.o codeB.o code_coupling.o
```

The code in `code_coupling.F90` is for coupling both codes and it is called within `codeB.f`, which I cannot change.

- Is there a possibility to compile `codeA.f` with some additional compiler flags so that the names of the `COMMON` blocks and subroutines don't interfere with each other?
- Is there some other way I can prevent the names from interfering with each other?

Comment: That the COMMONs share a name isn't an error the compiler should detect, as this is a fundamental feature of the language. What IS possible to detect is that the sizes of named COMMONs differs, but this can't be seen until link time and linkers typically don't care about this. Digital/Compaq Visual Fortran had an optional tool that could run  before the linker that would pick up on this, but I haven't seen it done elsewhere.

Comment: Put your common declaration in a file and include that file to declare the common block.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One (a little bit hacky) solution I have discovered is to compile `codeA.f` with the flag `-assume nounderscore`, and rename the functions that need to be called in `code_coupling.F90` manually with a trailing underscore:

```
ifort -c -fPIC -fp-model precise -assume nounderscore codeA.f
ifort -c -fPIC -fp-model precise codeB.f
ifort -c -fPIC -fp-model precise code_coupling.F90
ld -shared -o library.so codeA.o codeB.o code_coupling.o
```

Rename the subroutine `codeA_subroutine` within `codeA.f` to `codeA_subroutine_`.

Comment: That is really dirty. Do yourself and your codebase a favour and rename some of the identifiers so that the namespaces do not clash.  You need to make code adjustment with this option you propose anyway, why not do it properly?

Comment: My preferred solution would be to put the global variables in modules, with different module names in each component. You could do this in your own code and then the other code base could be left alone. Like @VladimirF, I believe you are setting yourself up for future problems using a compile switch approach.

Comment: @VladimirF the problem is that I don't know which functions need to be renamed. I would like to keep the code from program A as it is to just plug and play, since it is external software where I do not want to potentially rewrite the code each time an update comes.
I was hoping that there would be some compiler flag which automatically changes the names of subroutines (like leaving out the trailing underscores) so that subroutines with the same names from different codes don't collide.

Comment: @SteveLionel to clarify, I don't use any (relevant) global variables in my own code, the problem is a conflict of COMMON block and subroutine names between program A and program B. I can only access the source code of program A, since program B is in part precompiled, and the source code of program A is very lengthy and convoluted.

Comment: You do not want to rename functions, unless they clash too. you want to rename the common blocks. Or indeed, put the variables into a module instead. BTW, common blocks are nothing else than a way to share global variables.

Comment: @Ruhldieb Use modules and module variables instead of COMMON in Program A. You can leave Program B alone. Just don't name your modules the same as any of the COMMONs in Program B.